# Why does truffle compile report TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'contractName' of 'contract' as it is undefined?

Tags: truffle, solc

Why does `truffle compile` report `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'contractName' of 'contract' as it is undefined?`

```
$ npx truffle compile --all

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✔ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
> Compiling ./contracts/coins/CoinToken.sol
> Artifacts written to /home/james/workspace/rustedsolid/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Emscripten.clang
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'contractName' of 'contract' as it is undefined.
    at forContract (/home/james/workspace/rustedsolid/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/shims/NewToLegacy.js:5:13)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.save (/home/james/workspace/rustedsolid/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:123:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/home/james/workspace/rustedsolid/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/compile/run.js:38:1)
    at Command.run (/home/james/workspace/rustedsolid/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.5.3 (core: 5.5.3)
Node v16.13.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing truffle-config.js from this:

```
module.exports = {
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "pragma",
            settings: {
                optimizer: {
                    enabled: true,
                    runs: 200
                },
            }
        }
    },
};
```

To this - just changing the "pragma" to specify a compiler version:

```
module.exports = {
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.6.12",
            settings: {
                optimizer: {
                    enabled: true,
                    runs: 200
                },
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Makes the problem go away.

Comment: But I need my version to be pragma so I can support multiple solidity versions. 

Comment: Switch to hardhat?  That's what we did quite a while ago.